# Configuring commit interval for Confluent JDBC connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

In my app I'd like to configure the sink connector to commit offsets more frequently.

But it seems there is no configuration property to set this parameter explicitly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worker configuration

`offset.flush.interval.ms`

> Interval at which to try committing offsets for tasks.

Comment: how override this at connect level ?

I have a specific connect that need to override the worker conf

Comment: @raphaelauv I don't think connectors can override worker properties